# Issue with Afterpay Extension - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, admin-panel, afterpay

I am using **Magento v 1.9.3.10**,
We had an error with **Afterpay** not working last week, so I upgraded to the latest version and it worked ok.
However we couldn't use the other 2 payment methods (`Credit card` and `Paypal`). When they are selected in the checkout, the **"Place order now"** button doesn't do anything.
So I tried to go back to the previous **Afterpay** version, now it doesn't work and it doesn't let me put the `secret key` in the backend. it gives an error

> "An error occurred while saving this configuration: Invalid header
>   line detected"

both in `frontend` and `Admin`. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks heaps

Answer (score 0):

The Afterpay Magento 1 plugin v3.0 has been provided at the below URL:

o   URL:  https://github.com/afterpay/afterpay-magento